# How to install the e1071 package in R 2.15.0

Tags: r, cran

I want to use the `skewness()` and  `kurtosis()` functions from the *e1071* package. I have tried downloading the `e1071` package with

```
install.packages("e1071", dep = TRUE)
```

but it still doesn't seem to work. So I am wondering if it is the wrong version I installed. I've tried searching the CRAN site but I can't seem to find the version for R 2.15.0.

So I was wondering if I was doing it wrong or could someone please give me the link to the `e1071` package, version 2.15.0.

Comment: 2.15.0 is a bit dated.  Why not upgrade?  It's free! :-)

Comment: I would but unfortunately I don't have admin rights, thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: try ```install.packages("e1071", dep = TRUE, type = "source")``` perhaps there is no binary for that version.

Comment: You don't need admin rights to install R.

Comment: I've tried downloading the latest version but when I install it, the computer is asking me for the admin rights. : (

Comment: Try reinstalling `R` (3.0.2) from scratch, and just designate the installation as "user only" to avoid the admin headache.   Also, BTW,  I copied the `skew` and `kurtosis` funcs into my `cgwtools` package, so you could download that and pull the `R` modules for those functions. They don't require compilation.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this: 
 go to the

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html

get the windows [Finding the windows binary file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaweP.jpg)binaries for the library and put it in your library folder within the R installation. Then load the library within R

library(e1071)
 :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I did like this

if you are using Rstudio
go to packages in the right windows
click on install
write e1071
click install and it will work

Answer (score 1):

In R (for OSX) select `Packages & Data` -> `Package Installer` from the menu. If you haven't already select a Datacenter.

Then you can search for the package and install it via `Install selected` [image: Install selected screenshot]

Then you can use the package via:

```
> library(e1071)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for mac:
1) Download the binary - https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=e1071
2) Run R CMD INSTALL e1071_version.tgz
After this i tried to load the library but ran into the following problem.  If you don't you can skip the step below.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘e1071’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/R/library/e1071/libs/e1071.so':

dlopen(/Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/R/library/e1071/libs/e1071.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/R/library/e1071/libs/e1071.so
  Reason: image not found

3)  Copy /Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libR.dylib

A soft link might work as well but i just copied the whole lib.